# Doesn't work "Vagrant halt" command on CentOS7

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I have created a new CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) box by VirtualBox and Vagrant also I have followed the proper steps to create it

"Vagrant up" and "vagrant ssh" commands are working properly but when I try to "vagrant halt" I got the following error:

> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
> Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> shutdown -h now
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

When I go in to the box by "vagrant ssh" command  and run the "shutdown -h now" command I have been asked for the vagrant user password:

> [hww_vagrant@centos7x64 ~]$ shutdown -h now
> ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.login1.power-off === Authentication is required for powering off the system. Authenticating
> as: hww_vagrant Password:

It shouldn't ask me as I have add the following row on sudoers file:

> hww_vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

, and also I have commented the following row on sudoers file too:

> ## Defaults    requiretty

Here is the problem....as I have been asked for password when vagrant user tries to power off the box when I try to run "vagrant halt" it fails.

I think it should works with my configuration but still asking me the password for powering off the box by "vagrant" user...Does anybody what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: when you ssh into the machine and `shutdown -h now` it can ask you but if you do `sudo shutdown -h now` it should be ok ?

Comment: If I type _sudo shutdown -h now_ then I have been asked for password and it works because of my sudoers configuration file (_hww_vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL_), with this configuration I shouldn't be asked for password and I wouldn't need to type "_sudo_". What happens when I try to "_Vagrant halt_" command is vagrant user runs in backgroud "_shutdown -h now_" command and then  the vagrant user is not able to run because it is asked for password when with my configuration it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the configuration was ok. My vagrant user belong to wheel group and it was causing the error.

I have removed my vagrant_user from wheel group and it worked:

`usermod -G "" user_vagrant`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on this [post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50936) the following should work

create a file `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00-stop-reboot.rules` with the content

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate") == 0) {
    return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
  }
});

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.power-off") == 0) {
    return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
  }
});

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.reboot") == 0) {
    return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
  }
});

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.login1.suspend") == 0) {
    return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
  }
});
```

You will have to add that in packer (if thats what you use for box creation) or just before you package the box so this will be available when you run `vagrant halt` command

Comment: Thank about that. I don't understand this really well.with my sudoers configuration file vagrant user should be able to shutdown the box without sudo and password...hww_vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL....it seems a workaround for another thing different what I am asking.

Comment: well the error is pointed to `AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.login1.power-off` - not so familiar with centos7, for centos6 you dont need it , but might be one of the new things coming in 7x version

Comment: I have created the file with the content from here and it didn't work for me....it is weird because with the line: "vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL: in the sudoers files when the  vagrant user runs the "shutdown -h now" command shouldn't ask for password...